# Flutter Positioned class inside stack widget, won't accept a child property

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

the code runs, but I get an error which says 'child' parameter is undefined.
I tried flutter doctors, everything is fine.
I did flutter clean, and flutter upgrade.

the 'child' parameter simple doesn't show up with the auto fill from intellesence either when I press ctrl+spacebar.

I don't know what the issue is.

```
Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: size.height - 27,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: kPrimaryColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(36),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(36),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: -30.0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            // undefined error with 'child' here
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding),
              height: 54.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
       
      ),
```

Comment: fix your code please

Comment: Do you solve it?

Comment: yes. thanks for asking : ) 
flutter clean, and get packages, plus restart, plus new virtual device, seemed to be the answer,

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles well. It may due to syntax errors in *other parts of your code*. Thus try to find it out on other parts (or paste it to your question).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It got solved on it's own. I restarted the system and reinstalled the virtual device.
I ran 'flutter clean' and 'get packages' from pubspeck.yaml, works fine now.